# C# Attribute or Attribute 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, annotations, custom-attributes

I know you can add an attribute to methods in C# like this,

ex1.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Method()
{
//code
}
```

Which means the attribute must be satisfied to run `Method()`.

And I know you can stack attributes like this,

ex2.

```
[HttpPost]
[RequireHttps]
public void Method2()
{
 //More code
}
```

Which checks that both attribute1 'AND' attribute2 are satisfied before you can use `Method2()`.

But can you 'OR' Attributes? Something like this maybe?

ex3.

```
[HttpPost || RequireHttps]
public void Method3()
{
  //Even more code
}
```

So if either attribute is satisfied you can use `Method3()`.

Edit: Sorry was under the impression Attributes where called Annotations. Fixed that.

Comment: No, you can't. Out of curiosity, is your example academic, or is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Those are not annotations. They're attributes.

Comment: Attributes (which is what you posted as annotations) are just extra meta-data. They don't enforce _anything_.

Comment: @mccow002 I was trying to accomplish something like this. I'm not savvy enough to ask this question on purpose. :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which means the annotation must be satisfied to run Method()

That is a misunderstanding.

The `[HttpPost]` attribute is a directive, this method will only match a Post request. It is not a 'demand' like a security check. Only some attributes work that way.

But when considering them as 'requirements' : they work independently so that will always result in **AND** behaviour.

Comment: Funny enough my group is using custom attributes for security. And I need to either annotate the method with a check for 1 of 2 scenarios or find a different way to restrict access to the method. Ideas?

Comment: Custom attribute, like you said.. and maybe a PostSharp to make it easier..  Of course, you can always do it in method - if (!Permission.Validate(user, Permisisons.DoSomething)) throw new MyException(); - kind of thing

Comment: When you write your own Attributes and use for example strings for the Privileges you can make `[AuthorizeRequireOr("Admin", "Debugger")]`

Answer (score 1):

In C# they are not called annotations, but attributes.
By default attributes aren't used for anything except to decorate an class, method, property, etc. But through reflection you can use them for pretty much what you like, just like ASP.NET MVC does with `HttpPost` and `RequireHttps`.

Unfortunately they cannot be OR'ed.